# Polling heap size periodically on Android

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection

How can we poll the heap size (both native and managed) periodically on Android, so that we can draw a scatter plot of x:HeapSize-y:GCIteration? I've been considering two approaches:

1 Hack the DDMS code a bit to separate the memory usage part as a starting point of the polling tool. But it does not include native heap information, and I'm not sure about the difficulty of hacking the code.

2 Run `dumpsys meminfo` after each GC run. I can already get data with this approach. But I'm a bit confused about interpretation of the data. Specifically, what do the columns `native` and `dalvik` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the two approaches make sense. The second one is easier to implement, but we need to figure out the exact meaning of the output, which can be best done by reading the source code of `dumpsys`.